# trying to find cell null or not in a excel sheet in java

Tags: java, excel

im trying to read from a excel sheet but im getting stuck on a particular cell and its going on a infinite loop. i want to check weather a cell in a row is null or not, if its not null,it should proceed.im using java technology and working on it. could you modify my below code and help me out.

public class test {

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean b = false;
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Progress Day 8.xls"));

    //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
  //  System.out.println(workbook.);

    //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
        /*//sheet.
        System.out.println(sheet.getTopRow());
        sheet.g*/

    //Iterate through each rows one by one
    Iterator<HSSFRow> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
    System.out.println("no.of rows:"+sheet.getLastRowNum());
    int i=sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int j;



             while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
             {
                 HSSFRow row = rowIterator.next();
                 //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                 Iterator<HSSFCell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                 while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                 {
                     HSSFCell cell = cellIterator.next();
                     //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                     switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                     {
                         case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                             break;
                         case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                             {
                                 if(cell.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("add"))
                               {
                                   System.out.println("action");
                                 System.out.println("cellnu:"+cell.getCellNum());
                                  System.out.println("row nu:"+row.getRowNum());
                                /*
                                  while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                                  {
                                      if(cell.getCellNum()!=8||cell.getCellNum()!=9||cell.getCellNum()!=10||cell.getCellNum()!=13||cell.getCellNum()!=14)
                                      {
                                          if(cell!=null)
                                          {
                                              System.out.println("row:"+row.getRowNum()+ "cell"+cell.getCellNum()+"cell not null");
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              System.out.println("cell is null");
                                          }
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          System.out.println("row:"+row.getRowNum()+ "cell"+cell.getCellNum()+"is an exception");
                                      }
                                  }*/


                               }
                               else
                                  {
                                   System.out.println("break");
                                   }
                            break;
                            }
                 }

             }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: can you show sample input/expected output?

Comment: check for "" , " " and null. Dont just check for null..

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code as following:

```
HSSFCell cell = cellIterator.next();

if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
   //process cell
   switch (cell.getCellType()) {
      .... 
   }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Apache commons: Use StringUtils!
That has an insanely useful method isBlank(String) that checks for whitespace, empty strings and null.